# Want to delete UBUNTU 18.04 LTS from MacBook Air 2017 model

Tags: macos, install, unix

I'm completely new to using a Mac, and recently installed UBUNTU by following some YouTube videos and it worked fine. I added 50GB for the UBUNTU partition and 8GB for the SWAP partition. I now want to restore my 58 GB back to the MacOS partition and want to delete UBUNTU.

Can someone please give me a detailed step-by-step process on how to delete UBUNTU and reFInd and retrieve my MacOS back completely. Since it's a new Mac, I'm not worried about data loss and there are no important files.

Comment: Update: [macos-vanished-from-refind-and-cant-boot-into-macos-anymore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367440/macos-vanished-from-refind-and-cant-boot-into-macos-anymore). Also Ravi, you might want to comment on the answers below to let them know what has happened.

Answer (score 2):

Just perform an erase install. Boot to macOS recovery and then repartition the whole drive and the installer downloads from the internet.

- [How to completely reinstall Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367308/how-to-completely-reinstall-mac-os-x)

My answer here works best if you use internet recovery so you don’t need to mess with making a bootable usb and then get to recovery.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/315885/5472

In addition, there is no benefit to using a bootable USB or local recovery partition over just using internet recovery unless you already have the installer downloaded or a bootable Mac spare and handy. See [About macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said that you don't care about data loss but others who come here may.

This will prevent data loss on the macOS drive:

1. Boot to Ubuntu and backup and files you need to USB. If none, skip this step.
2. [Boot to Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) (Turn on your Mac and immediately press and hold Command (⌘)-R )
3. Select "Disk Utility" from the menu
4. Depending on your macOS version the steps maybe different. If on High Sierra or above you may need click View in the upper left and then "Show All Devices".
5. Select the top level disk and click "Partition". Remove all partitions except the macOS one (usually "Macintosh HD").
6. Restart the Mac and select macOS in rEFIned
7. Once in macOS, open Terminal
8. Run `diskutil list`. Look for the identifier where the name is "EFI". This can be done automatically with:
   `diskutil list | grep EFI | awk '{print $6}'`. It will likely be `disk0s1`.
9. Run the following commands replacing `disk0s1` with the correct identifier

---

```
sudo mkdir /Volumes/EFI
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/EFI
sudo rm -rfP /Volumes/efi/EFI/refind
sudo bless --setBoot --mount /
```

Source: https://superuser.com/a/1139054