# MacOS vanished from reFInd and can't boot into MacOS anymore

Tags: macos, unix, efi

Last night I tried deleting UBUNTU and SWAP  partitions on my MacBook Air 2017 model. But I could not remove the UBUNTU partition in Disk Utility after removing the SWAP partition. So I tried to restart so that it might fix it but unfortunately, reFInd did not show me the option of booting into MacOS. I can only boot into UBUNTU right now and I want to delete UBUNTU and retrieve MacOS back. Is there any solution for this? I don't mind about data loss. I'm completely new to using a Mac, so please explain any complex terminology that you're using so that a noob like me can understand. Kindly help me out and thank you so much in advance, I couldn't be more grateful :)

Comment: Can you please clarify *how* you tried deleting the UBUNTU and SWAP partitions? Did you follow the advice in any of the answers to your other [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367355/want-to-delete-ubuntu-18-04-lts-from-macbook-air-2017-model), or did you do something else? If you did something else instead, have you since tried booting into macOS Recovery as per the other answers?

Comment: I only deleted the SWAP partition but couldn't the system did not allow me to delete the UBUNTU partition (could not click on the - sign) so I restarted my laptop. But I could not boot into macOS anymore so I deleted the entire drive in recovery mode and reinstalling macOS right now. Will that work? I'm not concerned about data loss.

Comment: From the little information you provided It seems you tried to repartition the hard drive via another OS, and not MAC OS. If you decided to repartition the drive with another OS you will break the Mac OS. This issue happened to me as well when I tried to repartition my dual boot Windows/Mac Machine via the Windows OS. I lost all my data. In short: 1. Yes you will lose your data. 2. Do not repartition your Mac via another OS. Always use the Mac OS to repartition your drive.